# Rearange order of audio tracks in Premiere

Tags: premiere

Let's say I have the following arrangement of my audio tracks:

```
x ---------- 
y ---------- 
z ----------
```

and I want to have them arranged this way instead:

```
x ----------
z ----------
y ----------
```

What's the easiest way for me to make this happen?

(As an example, in Reason, I would grab the audio track I wanted to move and then simply place it where I want it. This does not seem to work in Premiere.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have discovered Premiere Pro doesn't let you move the tracks as easily as that (I wish it did!)

Fastest method would be to **create 1 or 2 empty tracks** (right click on a track label and select `Add Tracks`) **then use the Track Select Tool**  ('A' on the Keyboard) to quickly select an entire track:

[image: Premiere Pro Track Select tool]

(Click and hold lets you select and move the track at the same time).

*You could also select an entire track, Cut it, move your other tracks around, then Paste it back into a new track (you can choose which track it gets pasted into by clicking on the Track labels, Premiere will paste into the top most highlighted track)*

Comment: Oh dear! This seems cumbersome but thanks for the "sollution" ;)

Comment: @speldosa fingers crossed it has been improved in CS6!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep the track settings and move the entire track you can use the Premium version of PlumePack (it's a plugin).
You will be able to change the order of all your tracks without having to create empty tracks and keeping all audio effects and associated key-framing.

Answer (score -1):

On Mac, select footage that you want to move. Hold down ALT, use Up or Down arrows to move the entire track.

Comment: This doesn't keep move any of the channel settings, only the footage from track to track